# t Test, Chi Squared or logistic regression..?

Tags: logistic, t-test, chi-squared-test

20 subjects
Day 1. Shooting test - Basketball free throw shooting accuracy (number of successful shots out of 10)

Day 2. Given coaching and can practice technique.

Day 3. Shooting test again (as above)

Want to see if the coaching has positively or negatively impacted number of successful shots?

Comment: This experimental design will not be capable of telling you much about coaching.  You need to include a control group if you want to do that, so that you can compare two groups whose treatments differ *solely* in terms of coaching.

Comment: To expand on whuber's comment, you can't tell your results from what would happen if everything was as above but just the coaching part was absent; it's possible a simple learning effect from the first test to the second (caused by testing the first time and any practice on day 2) accounts for all the improvement seen, for example. Or maybe coaching makes things worse, compared to that learning effect, but is small so the overall effect is still an increase -- in that case you could end up concluding coaching helps when it does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please ignore the study design and inferences that can or cannot be made about coaching etc, this is part of a bigger study etc  The question is really - when the same people are tested on a task that has a binomial outcome (i.e. hit/miss, 0/1, yes/no) before and after some kind of intervention, how should you treat the data when choosing a statistical test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, when you have data like frequency, you should use a non-parametric test Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test.

Comment: please consider expanding upon your answer. As it stands now, it's really more of a comment. For example, why is this test appropriate? What makes other tests inappropriate?

Comment: I'm not this is appropriate here? There is no ranking to the data? The question is really - when the same people are tested on a task that has a binomial outcome (i.e. hit/miss, 0/1, yes/no) before and after some kind of intervention, how should you treat the data when choosing a statistical test.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple design you can use a Fisher-exact test. Say in day 1, x1 shoots were successful and y2 were missed; in day 3, x2 shoots were successful and y2 were missed.

Run the following R command:

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(x1,y1,x2,y2), nrow=2))
```

will tell you the odds ratio and the p-value (or google to find an online fisher exact test site).

If you have more than 2 outcomes then you can still do a chi-square test or Fisher-exact test. But if the outcomes are ordered, I would suggest a trend test, which would be more powerful than chi-square test.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I've edited your answer by including some spaces in front of your code snippet, so it is formatted as such. Have a look at our [editing help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to see some other options for how to format code, and some other neat features when writing questions and answers here!

Comment: Thanks for the response and i can see why you would suggest this. But im not sure... for example how would the test choice change if rather than 2 possible outcome (miss/hit) there was a 3rd option (i.e. miss completely, hit the ring, score)?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address the situation of more than two outcomes.